# ValueError when using df.style.apply().to_html()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble getting my dataframe to HTML when using `style.apply()`.

Using this line of code throws the same error whether I use `.render()` or `.to_html()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\test_data.csv')
print(df.style.apply(lambda x: f"color: {'red' if x == 'BAD' else 'black'}", axis=1).to_html())
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

However, when I use `.applymap()` I can use `.to_html()` without any errors but I want the condition to be applied row-wise and not element-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `axis=1` you receive a row and is expected that you return a list with the same length. From [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html):

> Parameters: func : function 
> **func** should take a Series if axis in [0,1] and return a list-like object of same length, ...

Therefore, you could use a list comprehension for each item in the row:

```py
df.style.apply(lambda row: [f"color: {'red' if i == 'BAD' else 'black'}" for i in row], axis=1).to_html()
```